# How can I request sms permissions in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, permissions, sms

I'm using [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) to request video and audio, but I can't get it to request permission to send SMS. I don't know if this is an issue with my phone's settings, my phone (Motorola Moto X4 XT1900-1), my phone's OS (Android 9), [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler), [Flutter](https://flutter.dev/), [Dart](https://dart.dev/), my implementation, or something else.

Once I've successfully received permission to send SMS, I plan to send SMS in the background without user input. I know how to pull up the messaging app with a message and recipient and have the user press send, but I'd rather not do it that way; I'm trying to take a no UI approach to it.

Here are some relevant lines of code.

pubspec.yaml:

```
permission_handler:
```

home.dart:

```
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
await [ Permission.camera, Permission.microphone, Permission.sms ].request();
```

The app will correctly request permission for camera and microphone, but not for sms. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

the problem i resolve by change version;

5.0.0 version can't correctly request sms ;

need change version ;it can work;

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in androidmanifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="yourappname>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<application>
.....
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had juent SMS directly from a flutter application successfully with flutter_sms package.

1. Ensure you add the SMS to your AndroidManifest:

   uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
   [image]
2. Request permission like this :

   var status = await Permission.sms.status;

   ```
    if (status.isDenied) {

     // We didn't ask for permission yet or the permission has been denied before but not permanently.

      await Permission.sms.request();

    }
   ```

This should prompt user for permission if not already granted.