# Printing to console when Flutter app has no permission to READ SMS

Tags: flutter, dart, android-permissions

I have a code like this:

```
SmsQuery query = new SmsQuery();
List<SmsMessage> AllMessages = [];
Timer? _timer;
var SMSPermStatus = Permission.sms.status;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (SMSPermStatus.isDenied == true) {
      print("give me read SMS perm");
    } else {
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) {
      try {
        GetAllMessages();
      } catch(e) {
        print("give me read SMS perm");
      }
      //GetAllMessages();
      //Page();
      print("refreshed");
      print(AllMessages); // []
    });
    }
    super.initState();
  }
  Future<void> GetAllMessages() async {
    List<SmsMessage> messages = await query.querySms(
      kinds: [SmsQueryKind.inbox],
      count: 50,
    );
    setState(() {
      AllMessages = messages;
    });
  }
```

If the application ha no permission to Read SMS, I want to print "no permission" to the console. But when I run the code I get this error:

[image]

How to solve the error? Thanks for help.

Comment: Check the existing [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61091116/how-can-i-request-sms-permissions-in-flutter-dart).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try` `catch` will not work here because `GetAllMessages` is a `Future`.

Try `await`-ing the `Future` and adding `async` to the `callback` of `Timer.periodic`.

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (t) async {
  try {
    await GetAllMessages();
  } catch (e) {
    print('exception caught: e');
  }
});
```